# Fetch Value using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a list defined in my controller. Now i want to get user input ,check if it exists in list in controller and then get all it related value.

**Controller**

```
private List<M> Ma()
   {
     List<M> md = new List<M>()
      { 
      new M{ R="a", A=300, T= 1, P=40, N=1200},
      new M{ R="Bl", A=100, T= 150, P=400, N=1200},
       };
      return mapData;
   }
```

Comment: Show the controller method for `DashData()`

Comment: Do you want to compare only with 'a' value? or with all values??

Comment: The map is initialized in the same controller, so, it will be empty, and u will do forEach over nothing!

Comment: @AlBaraaSh Compare var a with every R in list, as all R in ilst will have unique value,so var a will match only one R from list. And then i have to get the next value of matching R.

Comment: Your ajax method is passing only one item `{ name : a }` but the `DashData()` method does not even have a parameter named `name`. Then all you passing back is an empty list (and `qv.val(data.name);` makes no sense (typeof `List<MapModel>`  does not contain a property named `name`) so a little hard to understand exactly what you wanting to return.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am very nw to both AJAX and C#.  I want to compare var a value with R in list andd get all remaining item of matching R. So if var a = a it matches first R = "a". So i want to get all values thereafter Like A = 300,T = 1, etc

Comment: So if the value of the input is "a" and you pass that to the method, are you expecting to return only one `Map` object (i.e. `Maps { R="a", A=300, T= 1, P=40, N=1200 }`, and then access the properties of that `Map` in the view (i.e. you want to get say `A=300` and `N=200`)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ys that is what i am trying to achieve

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks. Will try myself too in mean time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, change the ajax call to

```
var a = $('input').val();
var qv = $('.act');
var tv = $('.tot'); // you don't seem to use this
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("DashData", "Home")', // never hard code the url!
  type: "POST",
  data: { a: a }, // change this
  success: function (data) {
    // access the properties of the object
    var A = data.A; // returns 300
    var T = data.T; // returns 1
    var P = data.P; // returns 40
    var N = data.N; // returns 200
  }
});
```

Side notes:

1. `var a = $('input').val();` will always return the value of the
   first `<input>` in the view, so suggest you use the `id` attribute
   (`$('#myInput').val();`)
2. You can also simplify it to `$.post('Url.Action("DashData", "Home"),
   {a: a }, function(data) { ... })`

Next modify the controller method to accept the parameter your passing and return the matching `Map` object

```
public ActionResult DashData(string a)
{
  // Get the first matching MapModel
    MapModel map = MapData().FirstOrDefault(m => m.R == a);
    return Json(map);
}
```

Comment: Your use of `qv.val(data.name);` made no sense so you may need to clarify exactly what you want to do with the values you return

Comment: I just want to set the values recieved in Vat T to another label in HTML

Comment: OK,so you should give the label an `id` attribute, and then `$('#myLabel').text(data.T);` (assuming by label, you mean an actual label - `<label>SomeText</label>`) For controls (input etc) use `.val()` and for other elements use `.text()`

Comment: Just one question. Do i set value in ajax success function or outside of ajax?

Comment: You might also want to check that you in fact returned a `MapModel` object - something like `if(data) { // set the value here } else { // oops - there was no matching map }`

Comment: Set the value inside the success callback (see last comment)

Comment: I am using   $.get(URL, function (data) { $("#db").html(data);}); to refresh partial view and display currently set value. But it is not working

Comment: What is `data`? (if that's the `MapModel` object you returned then that wont work. It's json data so you need to access the individual properties of `data` - e.g. `data.N` or `data.P`). The alternative is to return a partial view (i.e. html) in the controller method

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should look like this:

```
public ActionResult DashData(double a)
{
    return Json(md.FirstOrDefault(map=>map.a == a));
}
```

While md is the List you defined first

then ur AJAX call should be like this:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "../Home/DashData",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'a':a},
            success: function (data) {
                qv.val(data.a);
            }
        });
```